# req.query.countries Returns Empty Array on Filter

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose

Please help. Still relatively new with Nodejs and Angular. I have the below backend code on Nodejs and I am not able to filter the data by country from MongoDB through req.query.countries I can't for the life of me understand what is wrong here. Thanks in advance for any clues, pointers or solution.

My backend code is as follows
tourController.js file

```
exports.getToursByCountry = catchAsync(async (req, res, next) => {
let filter = {};
  if (req.query.countries) {
    console.log(req.query.countries);
    filter = { country: req.query.countries.split(',') };
  }

  console.log(filter);

  const tourList = await Tour.find(filter).populate('country');
  console.log(tourList);

  if (!tourList) {
    next(new AppError('Sorry could not retrieve tours by country', 400));
  }

  res.status(200).json({
    status: 'success',
    results: tourList.length,
    data: {
      data: tourList
    }
  });
});
```

tourModel.js file

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const slugify = require('slugify');
// const User = require('./userModel');

const tourSchema = new mongoose.Schema(
  {
    name: {
      type: String,
      required: [true, 'A tour must have a name'],
      unique: true,
      trim: true,
      maxlength: [
        120,
        'The tour name must have less or equal than 120 characters'
      ],
      minlength: [
        10,
        'The tour name must have more or equal than 10 characters'
      ]
    },
    slug: String,
    country: {
      type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
      ref: 'Country'
    },
    duration: {
      type: Number,
      required: [true, 'A tour must have a duration'],
      validate: {
        validator: val => {
          //'this' only works for the new posting of tour and not on update
          return val < 22;
        },
        message: 'The duration {VALUE} days should be below the 22 days'
      }
    },
    maxGroupPair: {
      type: Number,
      required: [true, 'A tour must have a maximum group pair size']
    },
    singleSupplement: {
      type: Number,
      required: [true, 'A tour must have a single supplment specified']
    },
    difficulty: {
      type: String,
      required: [true, 'A tour must have a difficulty'],
      enum: {
        values: ['easy', 'medium', 'difficult'],
        message: 'Difficulty is either: easy, medium nor difficult'
      },
      match: [
        new RegExp(/^[a-zA-Z\s]+$/),
        '{VALUE} is not valid. Please use only letters'
      ]
    },
    ratingsAverage: {
      type: Number,
      min: [1, 'Rating must be above 1.0'],
      max: [5, 'Rating must be below 5.0'],
      set: val => Math.round(val * 10) / 10
    },
    ratingsQuantity: {
      type: Number,
      default: 0
    },
    price: {
      type: Number,
      required: [true, 'A tour must have a price']
    },
    priceDiscount: {
      type: Number,
      validate: {
        validator: function(val) {
          //'this' only works for the new posting of tour and not on update
          return val < this.price;
        },
        message: 'Discount price {VALUE} should be below the regular price'
      }
    },
    overview: {
      type: String,
      trim: true,
      required: [true, 'A tour must have an overview']
    },
    imageCover: {
      type: String,
      required: [true, 'A tour must have a cover image']
    },
    images: [String],
    minimumAge: {
      type: String,
      required: [true, 'A tour must have a minimum age'],
      maxlength: [
        10,
        'The minimum age must have less or equal than 10 characters'
      ]
    },
    dateCreated: {
      type: Date,
      default: Date.now
    },
    availabilityDates: [String],
    isFeatured: {
      type: Boolean,
      default: false
    },
    secretTour: {
      type: Boolean,
      default: false
    },
    departureLocation: {
      // GeoJSON
      type: {
        type: String,
        default: 'Point',
        enum: ['Point']
      },
      coordinates: [Number],
      town: String,
      decription1: String,
      decription2: String
    },
    locations: [
      {
        type: {
          type: String,
          default: 'Point',
          enum: ['Point']
        },
        Area: String,
        coordinates: [Number],
        image: String,
        overnight: String,
        Meals: String,
        description: String,
        day: [Number]
      }
    ],
    guides: [
      {
        type: mongoose.Schema.ObjectId,
        ref: 'User'
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    toJSON: { virtuals: true },
    toObject: { virtuals: true }
  }
);

// tourSchema.index({ price: 1 });
tourSchema.index({ price: 1, ratingsAverage: -1 });
tourSchema.index({ slug: 1 });
tourSchema.index({ departureLocation: '2dsphere' });

tourSchema.virtual('id').get(function() {
  return this._id.toHexString();
});

tourSchema.set('toJSON', {
  virtuals: true
});

tourSchema.virtual('durationWeek').get(function() {
  return this.duration / 7;
});

// Virtual populate - this approach does not persist the infomation to the database
tourSchema.virtual('reviews', {
  ref: 'Review',
  foreignField: 'tour',
  localField: '_id'
});

//DOCUMENT MIDDLEWARE: runs before .save() and .create() & not on .insertMany
tourSchema.pre('save', function(next) {
  this.slug = slugify(this.name, { lower: true });
  next();
});


//QUERY MIDDLEWARE
tourSchema.pre(/^find/, function(next) {
  this.find({ secretTour: { $ne: true } });

  this.start = Date.now();
  next();
});

tourSchema.pre(/^find/, function(next) {
  //This will work on find method available in mongoose. 'this' calls populate on the current query
  this.populate({
    path: 'guides',
    select: '-__v -email -phone -street -apartment -suburb -zipCode -code -city'
  });

  this.populate({
    path: 'country',
    select: '-__v'
  });

  next();
});

tourSchema.post(/^find/, function(docs, next) {
  console.log(`Query took ${Date.now() - this.start} milliseconds`);
  // console.log(docs);
  next();
});

//AGGREGATION MIDDLEWARE
tourSchema.pre('aggregate', function(next) {
  if (!(this.pipeline().length > 0 && '$geoNear' in this.pipeline()[0])) {
    this.pipeline().unshift({
      $match: { secretTour: { $ne: true } }
    });
  }

  console.log(this.pipeline());
  next();
});

const Tour = mongoose.model('Tour', tourSchema);

module.exports = Tour;
```

tourRoutes.js route file

```
router.route('/').get(tourController.getToursByCountry);
```

Comment: Is req.query.countries an array ?

Comment: Yes, it is an object inside an array.

Comment: Does req.query.countries.split(',') code is working well ? It is an array so it can't be splitted. If there's an array and an object inside of it, req.query.countries[0].split(',')[0] can be used. Because after splitted array, you are gonna have an array as result. If it's not solution, can you share countries in req.query. Because problem is looking like into filter object.

Comment: Thanks but the suggested approach is not correct. On console.log(req.query.countries); I am getting 61ed829364aa758278cde7d5  On console.log(filter); I am getting { country: [ '61ed829364aa758278cde7d5' ] } however  on const tourList = await Tour.find(filter).populate('country');
  console.log(tourList); I am getting [] Empty Object In this instance I have filtered with one country, 61ed829364aa758278cde7d5 on Postman

Comment: You can use {country: {$in: req.query.countries.split(',') }}. I think, that's will work for you. Because we need to find countries which is inside an array. If filtered req.query.countries always will be an object in array, so you can write it as  req.query.countries.split(',')[0]. Also it works. But if it will be as objects inside an array, so $in is better for you. I hope, it works. If it doesn't, please write here.

Comment: This is not working. Allow to clarify that my above code was working whilst I had 10 documents/tours in MongoDB to filter by country or countries during the elementary stages of building the app. But now that I have 52 documents/tours I beginning to suspect that it has to do with Timeout and perhaps I need to run a pre/post middleware tourSchema.pre(/^find/,....)   tourSchema.post(/^find,....) on my tourModel.js

Comment: This is important information that needs to be _in the question_. Why do you suspect a timeout? What specific error messages are you getting?  Not enough information for us to help

Comment: No specific error at all except for the fact that I am getting an empty array. I will come back to you as I want to re-visit my current set-up on my pre/post middleware tourSchema.pre(/^find/,....) & tourSchema.post(/^find,....)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have resolved this. My seed json data imported into MongoDB under the field of country was a string in my database instead of an ObjectId.